# About the Aruba gap-db in the MM and MD

Tags: grafana, aruba

We have 2 group MM controllers and 3 clusters,

now we have two problems,

- When an AP is online in my network, it reg the MM controller, which will assign two MD controllers for the AP. if the AP into down, will have Down status log in the two MD controllers,

  Our current use `clear gap-db lms lms-ip x.x.x.x` clears the MD logs.

  I want to know if there are any other solutions. if you know, please tell me thanks!!!
- What's gap-db for Aruba? why is AP online at the MD, that'll save the AP information, even if we delete the AP in MM still have.

Because Prometheus + SNMP Exporter and use SNMP protocol. monitors the Aruba wireless AP count, the data needs real, from per MD. If the MD has multiple data will not be real.

`clear gap-db lms lms-ip x.x.x.x`

I'm trying to filter the origin data for the Grafana dashboard but failed.